# Get all objects where child list has all the objects from incoming list

Tags: entity-framework-core

My `where` condition is as follows:

`Where(x => crit.TagsLimiter.All(a => x.Tags.Any(b => b.Id == a.Id)))`

`crit.TagsLimiter` is the incoming `List<Tag>`

I am trying to get all the records where `x.Tags` has all the values from `crit.TagsLimiter`

I am getting the

`could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.` error

Comment: It does in that it works, so thank you for that, but it doesn't in that it doesn't really answer why my query didn't work. Nothing in it looks complex or not translated. Would be nice to understand.

Comment: EF Core doesn't support using local `List<T>` variables except with `Contains` so you can't use `All`.